# Why are we using ARMA model that mixes AR and MA model. Isn't AR or MA sufficient?

Tags: time-series, data-science, data-science-experience

Why are we using ARMA model that mixes AR and MA model. Isn't AR or MA sufficient?

I know that AR model is a function of previous readings and MA model is a function of previous errors, also know that identifying AR model is best done with PACF and know that identifying MA model is best done with ACF (and identifing AR model is best done with PACF)... 
But what is the intiuition behind using mixed model between the two

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The AR shows how the variable evolved with time, the MA makes the forecast error diminish with time.

It assumes :

- AR: *x<sub>t</sub>* depends linearly of *x<sub>t-1</sub>*, *x<sub>t-2</sub>*,...*x<sub>t-p</sub>*, where *x<sub>t</sub>* is the variable of interest.
- AM: *ε<sub>t</sub>* depends linearly of *x<sub>t-1</sub>*, *ε<sub>t-1</sub>*, *ε<sub>t-2</sub>*,...*ε<sub>t-q</sub>*, where *ε<sub>t</sub>* is the error.

AR is a characteristic of the model, AM a characteristic of the error.